# How to send email to Admin whenever a customer give 5 star review?

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, notifications, customization

I'm using "customer reviews for woocommerce" plugin. There is no option in the plugin to send Admin an email notification whenever a customer give 5 star review on any post.
Need some guidance on how can I override this plugin to get required functionality if possible or any hooks or helping code.

Comment: It seems [you already opened a support request](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/send-email-notification-to-admin/) on said plugin's forum and its developer seems to be  pretty active and responsive, so why post here as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can check count of review in the table of your plugin.

```
 if(count == 5){
      wp_
 }
```

Comment: would you like to elaborate about the email sending process itself ( not just checking the 5-star) - otherwise this answer is not really an answer...